# How to use :replace, :invalid and :undef args for encoding using CSV.read?

Tags: ruby, csv, encoding

Since ruby 1.9, CSV uses a parser that can perform encoding, if you use methods like:
`::foreach, ::open, ::read, and ::readlines`.

For example: `CSV.read('path/to/file', encoding: "windows-1252:UTF-8")` tries to read a file in windows-1252 and returns an array with utf-8 encoded strings.

If the encode conversion between charsets has undefined characters it gives an `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError`.

The String.encode method has some nice args to deal with this undefined characters:

`str = str.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: "" )`

Is there a way to use this kind of replace rules for undefined conversions between charsets with CSV parser?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is, indeed, a way. The trick is to define a custom converter that does the conversion you want using `String#encode`. Converters are run before CSV tries to do its automatic conversion to UTF-8. We pass the custom converter to `CSV.read` as the `:converters` option, along with the original `:encoding`:

```
UTF8_CONVERTER = ->(field) { field.encode('utf-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: "") }

CSV.read('foo.csv', encoding: 'windows-1252', converters: UTF8_CONVERTER)
```

Since there aren't any characters in Windows-1252 that aren't also in UTF-8, I'll demonstrate the other way around. Suppose you have this UTF-8 CSV file:

```csv
foo,bar
yes,no
```

And suppose I want to convert it to ASCII-8BIT (because reasons?). This gives me an error:

```
CSV.read('emoji.csv', encoding: 'utf-8:ascii-8bit')
# => Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+1F44D from UTF-8 to ASCII-8BIT
```

But if I define a custom converter that replaces those undefined characters, it works perfectly:

```
ASCII_CONVERTER = ->(field) { field.encode('ascii-8bit', replace: "@") }

CSV.read('emoji.csv', encoding: 'utf-8', converters: ASCII_CONVERTER)
# => [ [ "foo",  "bar"   ],
#      [ "yes@", "no@"] ]
```

(Note that `encoding: 'utf-8'` isn't strictly necessary here, since UTF-8 is the default, but it will be necessary if your file has a different encoding.)

Comment: KMoschcau solution also works. I opt for this one becouse I find more complete to define a converter as a proc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the replace behavior of String#encode, you will either have to encode the whole file content with it or do it line by line. **You will lose information with this.**

This is one way of doing it though:

```
file = File.open('path/to/file.csv')
file.each do |line|
  # keep in mind that the first parameter here is the destination encoding,
  # the second is the source encoding
  sanitized_line = line.encode('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
  fields_array = CSV.parse_line(sanitized_line)
  # do whatever you want with the fields you extracted
end
```

If your conversion from one encoding to another is pretty much guaranteed to not loose information (iso-8859-1 to utf-8 for example) I would really recommend to simply convert the file on reading.

Another thing to keep in mind is, that ruby does not try to figure out the encoding of a file you are reading on it's own. If you omit the parameter it only uses the default encoding for it's external and internal encoding. So you have to specify the encoding the file is in yourself. Ruby has no really reliable way of doing this, so in my case I ended up doing this (on a Ubuntu system):

```
encoding = `file --mime-encoding #{path_to_file} | awk '{print $2}'`.strip
arr_of_arrs = CSV.read(path_to_file, encoding: "#{encoding}:utf-8")
```

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that if any fields contain a newline (which is valid in a quoted field), this will fail.

Comment: This solution works. I find Jordan's one more complete. Thanks.